# Why RSA decryption fails for corrupted data

Tags: cryptography, rsa, padding

Why if I change a single bit of a given RSA encrypted message and then I try to decrypt it using the appropriated key, I get a padding error? Does anyone know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding has a certain format which can be checked during decryption. If the format doesn't match due to some (malicious) manipulation then the decryption must fail.

RSA has a long history with padding schemes. Textbook RSA (no padding is applied) can be attacked in some scenarios very easily. With PKCS#1 padding we already have some either static or random padding (depending on the version of the standard) applied, but it used some specific markers which might result in accidental padding matches during decryption. OAEP improved the situation where you can be very sure that a successful decryption means that the ciphertext was not manipulated.